# Type casting to generic type?

Tags: java, generics, casting

```
public class NumberAnalyzer<T extends Number>{

public T average() {
    Double temp = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberArray.size(); i++) {
        temp += numberArray.get(i).doubleValue();
    }
    temp /= numberArray.size();
    return (T) temp;
}
```

How would I type cast this so when I pass in an Integer or a Double it gives me the correct type I passed in? At the moment it's always coming back as a Double.

Is this what you meant?

```
public class NumberAnalyzer<T extends Number> {
private Function<Double, T> castFn;

NumberAnalyzer(Function<Double, T> castFn) {
    this.castFn = castFn;
}

private ArrayList<T> numberArray;
public T average() {
    Double temp = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberArray.size(); i++) {
        temp += numberArray.get(i).doubleValue();
    }
    temp /= numberArray.size();
    return castFn.apply(temp);
}
```

This is my test class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> intArrayListTest = new ArrayList<>();
    intArrayListTest.add(22);
    intArrayListTest.add(7);
    intArrayListTest.add(839);
    intArrayListTest.add(24);
    intArrayListTest.add(99);
    NumberAnalyzer<Integer> numTest = new NumberAnalyzer<>(intArrayListTest);
```

So the answer I'm looking for is if I pass in a int Array that has values of 8,9 and 66 it the average would be: 27

If passing a double array with the same values it would give me: 27.66

At the moment it would always return a double value even if i pass in an int.

Comment: Aside: use `double temp` instead of `Double temp`, to avoid repeatedly unboxing and boxing.

Comment: Your variable `temp` is a `Double`, so of course the method always returns a `Double`. Casting variables of non-primitive types does not somehow convert objects from one type to another.

Answer (score 1):

Casting a reference-typed variable to another reference type doesn't actually do anything to the value - it's just a way of saying to the compiler "trust me, I know more type information than you".

So, casting an `Integer` to a `Double` wouldn't make it a `Double`, it would just trick the compiler into believing the type, leading to subsequent problems when it tries to use that `Integer` as a `Double`.

You aren't looking to *cast* here, you are looking to *convert*.

You would need to pass in a `Function<Double, T>` or a `DoubleFunction<T>`, either as a parameter to the method or the constructor.

```
public T average(Function<Double, T> castFn) {
   // ...
   return castFn.apply(temp);
}
```

or

```
public class NumberAnalyzer<T extends Number>{
  private Function<Double, T> castFn;

  NumberAnalyzer(Function<Double, T> castFn) { this.castFn = castFn; }

  public T average() {
    // ...
   return castFn.apply(temp);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.function.Function.apply(Object)" because "this.castFn" is null

Comment: "because "this.castFn" is null" set it to something other than null.

Comment: What would I set it to? sorry I don't fully understand that code you added

Comment: e.g. `Double::intValue` or `d -> (int) d`.

Comment: Where exactly would i put that? castFn = d -> (int) d; inside my NumberAnalyzer class?

Comment: You can't put it inside the class because the class is generic, and `d -> (int) d` only converts a double to an int. As I say in my answer: "You would need to pass in ... either as a parameter to the method or the constructor".

Comment: I updated the code, what would my main method look like? I'm not sure how to pass it into a constructor